# Run Python Code on NVIDIA GPU

Tags: python, cuda, gpu, igraph, nvidia

I am new to programming in python on top of a NVIDIA GPU so have the following problem statement.

I'm trying to perform social network analysis on Youtube Dataset(http://netsg.cs.sfu.ca/youtubedata/) in 2 parts using python's igraph library.

1. In the 1st part I will be looking at degree distributions, centrality measures and computing HITS scores, page rank, clustering coefficients.
2. In the 2nd part I will be working on link prediction between videos using supervised learning, PropFlow, proximity scoring, supervised random walks.

Currently I am done with the pre-processing part but when I try to generate graphs on a part of our data set(the subset containing 5538 unique nodes) using igraph library in PyCharm IDE, the code runs for 3 hours with no end in sight.

**I wanted to know will running the python code on NVIDIA GPU on my machine will speed things up?**

Also is there any way to run code written in pycharm IDE directly on GPU using CUDA(https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=7&target_type=exelocal) without python's Anaconda distribution ? I tried searching online for the same but couldn't find any.

***System Configuration***

1. Windows 7(64 bit)
2. NVIDIA GeForce 820M GPU(2 GB)
3. RAM (8 GB)
4. Python 2.7.14
5. PyCharm IDE(Community Edition)

Comment: In a word, no....

Comment: I don't quite get your limitations on the programming environment and limitations, but you may want to have a look at numba @vectorize directive https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html

Comment: @FlorentDUGUET Hi, could you suggest something for this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131479/how-to-parallelise-this-graph-operation-using-gpu

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using a Python module, maybe most of the computation is being done inside it, so you will need to improve the library, not your code.

On the other hand, if you have your own processes you could improve them by using [PyCUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda), but please be aware that not all code is parallelizable, and you will not always get an amazing speed up.
You could profile your code, and see if it follow a certain [Flynn's taxonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flynn's_taxonomy) that allow you to use a GPU kernel.

Sadly there is no magic plugin that will run your code on the GPU from using PyCharm.

Comment: Any suggestions for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131479/how-to-parallelise-this-graph-operation-using-gpu